# Why does this test question use "to Verb-ing"?

Tags: verbs, exam-questions

The question:

> She is attending the seminar with a view to _______ more qualifications.
>
> A. acquire
>   B. having acquired
>   C. acquiring
>   D. being acquired

And the answer is C. I don't understand because we uasually use to {infinitive} or just {V}-ing. Is this answer wrong or it is other grammar?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is not wrong. The expression [**with a view to doing something**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/with-a-view-to-doing-sth), in terms of its structure, requires the use of the "ing" form of a verb (that's just how it works). The *to* here is not an infinitive marker. It's the preposition *to* which in this case has the meaning of approaching or reaching a particular condition. That's why the correct answer is C (*acquiring*):

> She is attending the seminar **with a view to acquiring more qualifications**.

Comment: Perhaps so, but I don't like the wording in the test question. Were I saying this to someone, I'd use something like "with the goal of", not "with a view to".